# Truncate numbers in dollar signs

Tags: math-mode, siunitx

Is there any way to truncate numbers inside dollar signs? I found a solution using `siunitx` and `\num{somenumber}`, but I have a very large output with dollar signs. To make things worse, some of the numbers are in a format like this: `$\phantom{000}0.024$` so I can't even replace the dollar signs with \num (I think phantom doesn't work well with \num). So is there any workaround, to truncate the presented number inside dollar signs, to 2 digits after decimal for example? For example: 2.5678 -> 2.56

Comment: By "round", do you mean to the closest integer?  Also, just to make sure, you mean "round" and not "truncate"?

Comment: I actually meant truncate. Sorry, my English is not my first language. For example 2.5678 will be 2.57. Will edit the main post.

Comment: Truncating a number actually means making 2.56 out of a 2.5678. If the `\phantom{000}` is there for alignment purposes, a `S` column provided by `siunitx` would allow aligning numbers on the decimal marker inside a `tabular`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction about truncating. It doesn't matter to me that much if it is 2.56 or 2.57, but just to have fewer digits. I wasn't aware of the purpose of phantom, it is something that I have in my output whether I like it or not. So I guess I can remove all of them, but I still wonder if there is a way to truncate dollar signs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the `\phantom`s are to the left of the decimal...

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{specialmath}{\catcode`$=\active}{}
{\catcode`$=\active
\gdef$#1${\dollar#1.000\enddollar}
\gdef\dollar#1.#2#3#4\enddollar{\ensuremath{#1.\ifx.#200\else#2\ifx.#30\else#3\fi\fi}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{specialmath}
$2$\par
$2.$\par
$2.3$\par
$2.35$\par
$2.357$\par
$2.3578$\par
$52.3578$\par
$\phantom{000}52.3578$
\end{specialmath}

The dollar is restored $x^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

At the OP's request, here is a version that will not add a decimal if there is none in the originally presented number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{specialmath}{\catcode`$=\active}{}
{\catcode`$=\active
\gdef$#1${\dollar#1.\relax\relax\enddollar}
\gdef\dollar#1.#2#3#4\enddollar{\ensuremath{%
  #1\ifx\relax#2\else%
    \ifx.#2.00\else.#2\ifx.#30\else#3\fi\fi%
  \fi%
}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{specialmath}
$2$\par
$2.$\par
$2.3$\par
$2.35$\par
$2.357$\par
$2.3578$\par
$52.3578$\par
$\phantom{000}52.3578$
\end{specialmath}

The dollar is restored $x^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great. Is there a way to keep integers without a decimal?  Meaning 2, will stay 2, and not 2.00.

Comment: @Nashh I have edited my answer to add that solution, as well.